# Underscore return indeces of objects in an array where word exists in sentences within objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, search, underscore.js, indexof

I have an array with arrays inside like this;

```
    var lines = [
["1","1","1","A man is walking."]
,["1","1","2","Noooo he's not, no way!"],
["1","1","3","You can't see that far can you?"],
["1","1","4","I can, he stopped, he's looking right at us"]
];
```

And with Underscore I can get an array inside "lines" if line[4] is exactly the search sentence, like, "A man is walking." would return lines[0];

So I want to be able to search through these sentences(lines) with just a word(s), like "Walking" should match and return the first array in 'lines' since there's a sentence that contains the word.

```
_.some(lines, function(array){
            var result = (array[4] == 'walking' && array[4]);
        if (result !== false){
                console.log(result);
            } 
});
```

How do I modify this underscore function, or if there's a correct one I should use or if at all, even if its something without underscore, please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't have the luxury of ES6's find, in plain javascript:

```
var lines = [
["1","1","1","A man is walking."],
["1","1","2","Noooo he's not, no way!"],
["1","1","3","You can't see that far can you?"],
["1","1","4","I can, he stopped, he's looking right at us"]
];

function lineSearch(arr, term) {
  var indices = arr.map(function(innerArr, index) {
    return innerArr[3].indexOf(term) > -1 ? index : null;
  }).filter(function(x) {
    return x !== null;
  });

  var results = arr.map(function(innerArr, index) {
    return innerArr[3].indexOf(term) > -1 ? innerArr : null;
  }).filter(function(x) {
    return x !== null;
  });

  return {indices: indices, results: results};
}

console.log(lineSearch(lines, "can"));
```

should give:

```
 {
  indices: [2, 3],
  results: [["1", "1", "3", "You can't see that far can you?"], ["1", "1", "4", "I can, he stopped, he's looking right at us"]]
 }
```

Comment: This does return lines where "walking" occurs, but it only returns the first found found array, it should, continue iterating and return the rest and their indexes.

Comment: Sorry I got hung up on "should match and return the first array". I've updated my answer to do what you need now.

Comment: Checked it, its much faster, and How would you do it if you were using ES6's "Find"?

Comment: Well I wrote that part about find when I thought you were just looking for the first found result. So it's not actually useful in your case. It's basically a more efficient version of filter that stops after it finds the first element that meets the condition in your callback. You can find more detailed info about the function here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Answer (score 1):

`_.some` returns a boolean. You need to `filter` the matching results which you get by seeing if the search term is within the string. Indexes start at `0` so you need to check index 3 instead of 4.

Working example:

```js
    var lines = [
        ["1", "1", "1", "A man is walking."],
        ["1", "1", "2", "Noooo he's not, no way!"],
        ["1", "1", "3", "You can't see that far can you?"],
        ["1", "1", "4", "I can, he stopped, he's looking right at us"]
    ];


    var input = document.getElementById('search');
    var output = document.getElementById('output');

    input.onkeyup = function (event) {
        var value = this.value;
        var results = _.filter(lines, function (array) {
            return array[3].indexOf(value) > -1;
        });

        var indexes = _.map(results, function(array) {
          return lines.indexOf(array);
       });

        output.innerHTML = '<pre>Indexes: ' + JSON.stringify(indexes) + '</pre><pre>' + JSON.stringify(results, null, 2) + '</pre>';
    };
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/2.1.0/lodash.compat.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search">
<output id="output"></output>
```